# How to make a rounded corner rectangle with a cut corner using css?

Tags: css

I wish do a rectangle in CSS with graceful degradation to work in IE8+. And work fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers.

Supposed HTML Tag:
<span class="tag tag-gray">FRETE GRÁTIS</span>

See sample:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/roundcutcorner.png/

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure CSS Solution

Here's the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Td42n/2/) with comparison to original image and the CSS:

```
span.tag {
 margin:4px 5px;
 position:relative;
 border-radius:5px;
 background:red;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:.6em 4.5em;
 text-align:center;
}
span.tag-gray {
 background: #7c7d80; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7c7d80 0%, #7c7d80 50%, #66686b 51%, #66686b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7c7d80), color-stop(50%,#7c7d80), color-stop(51%,#66686b), color-stop(100%,#66686b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7c7d80 0%,#7c7d80 50%,#66686b 51%,#66686b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7c7d80 0%,#7c7d80 50%,#66686b 51%,#66686b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7c7d80 0%,#7c7d80 50%,#66686b 51%,#66686b 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top, #7c7d80 0%,#7c7d80 50%,#66686b 51%,#66686b 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7c7d80', endColorstr='#66686b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 color:#fff;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-size:.7em;
 font-weight:bold;
}
span.tag:after {
 /* right, height, and width should equal eachother */
 right:-18px;
 height:18px;
 width:18px;
 content:".";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 font-size:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#fff;
 -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
 -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
 -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform-origin:0 0;
 transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Assuming the HTML is:

```
<span class="tag tag-gray">FRETE GRÁTIS</span>
```

### Gotchas

- To get it to work with older (and other) browsers, you may want to add the prefixed versions of `border-radius`
- To get it to work in non-webkit/moz browsers, simply add the corresponding prefixed versions of `transform` and `transform-origin`
- The "cut" cannot be transparent, but you can make it appear to be by setting it to the same color(s) as the background
- Due to using `border-radius`, you cannot set `div.cut`'s `overflow` to `hidden` as the `div`'s background will bleed through along the outer edge of the radius, so you have to make sure you have enough room outside of the element to avoid covering other elements/text. A workaround is to set the background to a gradient and have the outer edge be transparent (aka right side)

Comment: Setting the background to a gradient or textured color, we have a problem with span.tag:after because it is setted to #fff color. Any idea to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: There are a couple possible solutions: 1) Use the textured color for the background of `span.tag:after`; 2) Use `overflow:hidden;` on `span.tag` if the texture/gradient is close enough in color to the background of `span.tag` for the **very thin** line along the `border-radius` to blend in; 3) Set the background of `span.tag:after` to a gradient that is transparent along the right side (or, if you're even more daring, two gradients that are transparent in TL and BR corners); --- I may have a couple other solutions in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

a funny but probably not the best solution is to cover your image with [triangle div](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) using position-absolute and z-index :). To round your corners you can use [border-radius](http://border-radius.com/) (but it will not work in IE8 unless you add js to support css3 properties)

Answer (score 0):

Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RVT/) something similar to what you need?
Here is the code for it

```
`.tag.tag-gray {

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 300px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 300px;

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="rounded">FRETE GRÁTIS<div class="tri"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.tri {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;   
}

.rounded {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #c0c0c0 0%,
        #333333);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#c0c0c0),
        to(#333333));
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;     
    width:120px;
    position:relative;
}
```

And for IE8, I'd use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using one image, you could make a simple white triangle image with a transparent background (PNG 24), then do something like this:

```
.tag-grey {
    background: grey url(triangle.png) no-repeat right top;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
     border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
 }
```

It's not *pure* css, but it uses a standard CSS method. The upshot is that this will work in IE7 and up, just without the other rounded corners.

Comment: This solution sacrifices the two-color background/gradient. Also, you might want to mention it requires an extra resource (which may be moved/renamed inadvertently and would result in a square corner in modern browsers) and is more difficult to change (changing background requires changing image, rather than just a color code).